# How to catch the timeout of a WCF client before it happens? (alert clients they will be disconnected)

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

Is it possible to (duplex service) catch the timeout of a client and wake them back up?

It seems the OperationContext InstanceContext has events for closing/closed which is automatically triggered when the state of the connection is closed. But I want to get in before that and for example warn a user of a timeout, possibly extend the timeout, things like that.

How do I hook into this?

Comment: (Disclaimer: not tested.) You could get the [EndPoint property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553831.aspx) of your client object, from which you can get the [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.binding.aspx) from which you can get the [timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.aspx). Initiate a timer on idling before asking to "keep alive". If responded affirmative, send a "KeepAlive" message to your service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I really want to know how to do this (if possible) through the WCF object model itself. I don't **want** to figure out the timeout (i'm working server side btw) and have a timer watching it.